# support of a distribution coincides with the support of a function

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to show that if $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbf{R}^n)$ then the induced distrubtion $D_f(\phi) = \int_{\mathbf{R}^n} f\phi$ has $\mathrm{supp}(D_f) = \overline{\{x : f(x) \neq 0\}}$. I know that the support of $D_f$ is the largest open set on which $D_f$ vanishes, but I don't know how to relate that to $f$. (For reference, this is Reed & Simon, Exercise V.28b).

Answer (score 2):

If $\phi$ is such that $\text{supp}(\phi)\cap\text{supp}(f)=\emptyset$, then $\displaystyle\int_{{\bf{R}}^{n}}f(x)\phi(x)dx=0$, so $\text{supp}(D_{f})\subseteq\text{supp}(f)$.

Now fixed an $x_{0}$ such that $f(x_{0})\ne 0$, say, $f(x_{0})>0$, then $f(x)>f(x_{0})/2$ for some ball $B_{\eta}(x_{0})$. Assume that $x_{0}\notin\text{supp}(D_{f})$, then we can find some $\delta>0$ such that $B_{\delta}(x_{0})\cap\text{supp}(D_{f})=\emptyset$. We can assume that $\delta<\eta$. Now find a $\phi$ such that $\text{supp}(\phi)\subseteq B_{\delta}(x_{0})$ and that $\phi(x)=1$ on $B_{\delta/2}(x_{0})$. Then $\displaystyle\int_{{\bf{R}}^{n}}f(x)\phi(x)dx\geq\int_{B_{\delta/2}(x_{0})}f(x)\phi(x)dx\geq (f(x_{0})\delta^{n})/2^{n+1}>0$, so $\phi$ is such that $\text{supp}(\phi)\cap\text{supp}(D_{f})=\emptyset$ but $\displaystyle\int_{{\bf{R}}^{n}}f(x)\phi(x)dx\ne 0$, this is a contradiction. We conclude that $x_{0}\in\text{supp}(D_{f})$ and hence $\text{supp}(f)\subseteq\text{supp}(D_{f})$.

Comment: Why does the first line show that $\mathrm{supp}(D_f) \subset \mathrm{supp}(f)$?

Comment: Actually I have used a slightly different definition of the support of a functional: $\text{supp}(D_{f})$ is defined as the smallest closed set $K$ (intersection of all such $K$) such that whenever a test function $\phi$ is such that $\text{supp}(\phi)\cap K=\emptyset$, then $\left<D_{f},\phi\right>=0$.

Comment: So $\text{supp}(f)$ is one of a such $K$ that satisfying the condition, so as $\text{supp}(D_{f})$ being the smallest one, we have $\text{supp}(D_{f})\subseteq\text{supp}(f)$.

Comment: Hm. I wonder how to use the definition I have for the forward direction.

Comment: According to your definition, by denoting $u=D_{f}$, actually it is like $\text{supp}(u)=\{x\in{\bf{R}}^{n}: x~\text{has no neighborhood on which }u~\text{vanishes.}\}$. So now $u$ vanishes on $(\text{supp}(f))^{c}$, but $(\text{supp}(f))^{c}$ is open, so $(\text{supp}(f))^{c}$ cannot have intersection with $\text{supp}(u)$, if not, then $(\text{supp}(f))^{c}$ is a neighborhood of some $x\in\text{supp}(u)$ on which $u$ vanishes, so $(\text{supp}(f))^{c}\cap(\text{supp}(u))=\emptyset$, and hence $(\text{supp}(f))^{c}\subseteq(\text{supp}(u))^{c}$, and hence the desired inclusion.